# AS3 - Adjust image colors

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, adjustment

I'm adjusting image colors through the function below. The problem is that if I need to switch a **colorFilter** value to **0** it's not working but if I enter **0.1** instead of **0** it works.
How to make it work without that workaround?

```
import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;

var colorFilter:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
var mColorMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter;
var mMatrix:Array = [];
var MC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

function adjustColors():void
{

    colorFilter.hue = 50;
    colorFilter.saturation = 50;
    colorFilter.brightness = 50;
    colorFilter.contrast = 12;

    mMatrix = colorFilter.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
    mColorMatrix = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);

    MC.filters = [mColorMatrix];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by '**colorFilter** value'?

Comment: I mean this: `colorFilter.hue /  colorFilter.saturation /  colorFilter.brightness / colorFilter.contrast`

Answer (score 2):

I tested this by adding an argument to adjustColors() and calling it twice, and I see the same problem. I think it's just a bug where it ignores zero values.

It's not much of a better workaround, but if you just create a new AdjustColor each time, it should work correctly:

```
import fl.motion.AdjustColor;
import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter;

var colorFilter:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
var mColorMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter;
var mMatrix:Array = [];
var MC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

function adjustColors():void
{

    colorFilter = new AdjustColor();

    colorFilter.hue = 50;
    colorFilter.saturation = 50;
    colorFilter.brightness = 50;
    colorFilter.contrast = 12;

    mMatrix = colorFilter.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
    mColorMatrix = new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);

    MC.filters = [mColorMatrix];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround for reference:
Just use the logical OR assignment when you set each property.
That way if a value is 0 it will evaluate to false and .1 will be assigned instead:

```
var colorMat:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter();
var colorAdjust:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();

const colorsAdj:Array = 
[
    // BRIGHTNESS, CONTRAST, SATURATION, HUE
    [-20,0,20,-50],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,17]
];

function setColorMat(colorID:int):void
{
    colorAdjust.brightness = colorsAdj[colorID][0] ||= .1;
    colorAdjust.contrast = colorsAdj[colorID][1] ||= .1;
    colorAdjust.saturation = colorsAdj[colorID][2] ||= .1;
    colorAdjust.hue = colorsAdj[colorID][3] ||= .1;
    colorMat.matrix = colorAdjust.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
}
```

That way you avoid recreating a new ColorMatrixFilter each time, in case it really change something...
And you keep a nice clean array... ;-)